# Catch all routing except for /graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I have a node.js server application that uses express and apollo-server-express to server my application. I want to serve my react client using a catch-all routing method, however, I still want to expose the `/graphql` endpoint. How can I do this so that `/graphql` doesn't get caught in the rest of my routing? Thanks.

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/graphql', (request, response) => {
  // ? not sure what to do here.l
});

app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to manually define the `/graphql` route if you are indeed using the `apollo-server-express` package which is recommended if you want to combine Apollo with the express middleware. The [official documentation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/main/packages/apollo-server-express) actually puts you on the right track. In your specific case, your server setup should look someting like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  console.log('catch-all hit.');
});

app.listen({ port: 3000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:3000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

Just make sure that you define your catch-all route AFTER executing `server.applyMiddleware`, which sets up the `/graphql` endpoint for you. That way the `/graphql` endpoint is hit first and will be used to handle those requests. All the other requests will be handled by the catch-all.